# Webpack 5 can't resolve url path of background-image

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-5, urlloader

> I have tried multiple solutions like url-loader configuration but can't be helpful. I also tried asset/resource and asset/inline but not worked for me.
> Any kind of help is appreciated. Remember I am using Webpack5.

**Webpack.config.js** (This is my webpack file)

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const FaviconsWebpackPlugin = require("favicons-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./src/index.js",

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/",
  },
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx", ".css"],
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(s[ac]|c)ss$/i,
        use: ["css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },

      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        type: "asset",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        type: "asset",
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
      favicon: "./public/favicon.ico",
    }),

    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": JSON.stringify(process.env),
    }),
  ],
};
```

> If I commit this background-image line then build will be compiled successfully

**file.scss**

```
.mtd-sales {
  background-image: url("../../../images/Rounded_Rectangle4_orders.png");
}
```

[image: While running npm run build it throws this error]

[image: This is my image folder structure, Image lies in file _authentication.scss]

**Node version: v14.18.1**.

> **Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "nazox",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^18.0.1",
    "@fullcalendar/bootstrap": "^5.7.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.7.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.7.0",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^5.7.0",
    "@lottiefiles/react-lottie-player": "^3.5.0",
    "@lourenci/react-kanban": "^2.1.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.7",
    "@progress/kendo-react-dialogs": "^5.13.0",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "1.6.8",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.6",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-popups": "^21.1.41",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@toast-ui/react-chart": "^1.0.2",
    "@vtaits/react-color-picker": "^0.1.1",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "apexcharts": "^3.17.0",
    "availity-reactstrap-validation": "^2.6.1",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.20.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
    "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^3.1.0",
    "bootstrap-react-treetable": "^2.0.2",
    "broadcast-channel": "^4.18.1",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "chartist": "^0.11.4",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "compressorjs": "^1.1.1",
    "cookie": "^0.5.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "dompurify": "^2.3.10",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.4",
    "echarts": "^4.7.0",
    "echarts-for-react": "^2.0.15-beta.1",
    "favicons-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "filerobot-image-editor": "^3.12.17",
    "firebase": "^9.8.1",
    "fontkit": "^2.0.2",
    "google-maps-react": "^2.0.2",
    "highcharts": "^9.3.3",
    "highcharts-react-official": "^3.1.0",
    "html-to-image": "^1.11.4",
    "i18next": "^19.4.5",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^4.2.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "lottie-react": "^2.3.1",
    "mdbreact": "^4.25.4",
    "metismenujs": "^1.1.0",
    "mkdirp": "^1.0.3",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.28",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "nouislider-react": "^3.3.7",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^3.3.122",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.6",
    "react-autosuggest": "^10.1.0",
    "react-avatar": "^4.0.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "react-bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^7.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap-editable": "^0.6.1",
    "react-bootstrap-sweetalert": "^5.1.9",
    "react-bootstrap-table-next": "^4.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-editor": "^1.4.0",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator": "^2.1.2",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit": "^2.1.2",
    "react-chartist": "^0.14.3",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.9.0",
    "react-circle-slider": "^1.6.2",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-corner-ribbon": "0.0.5",
    "react-countdown": "^2.2.1",
    "react-cropper": "^1.3.0",
    "react-csv": "^2.2.2",
    "react-custom-checkbox": "^2.0.1",
    "react-customizable-progressbar": "^1.0.3",
    "react-date-range": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.14.4",
    "react-dropzone": "^10.2.1",
    "react-export-table-to-excel": "^1.0.6",
    "react-flatpickr": "^3.10.7",
    "react-google-invisible-recaptcha": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "react-google-recaptcha-v3": "^1.9.7",
    "react-grid-carousel": "^1.0.1",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-i18next": "^9.0.10",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-image-gallery": "^1.2.9",
    "react-image-lightbox": "^5.1.1",
    "react-images": "^1.2.0-beta.7",
    "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
    "react-js-pagination": "^3.0.3",
    "react-jvectormap": "^0.0.16",
    "react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.5.5",
    "react-loading-skeleton": "^3.1.0",
    "react-minimal-side-navigation": "^1.9.2",
    "react-modal-video": "^1.2.7",
    "react-multi-select-component": "^4.2.3",
    "react-otp-input": "^2.4.0",
    "react-owl-carousel": "^2.3.3",
    "react-pdf": "4.0.5",
    "react-pdf-to-image": "^1.0.2",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.8",
    "react-phone-input-2": "^2.14.0",
    "react-pro-sidebar": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.5",
    "react-rangeslider": "^2.2.0",
    "react-rating": "^2.0.5",
    "react-rating-tooltip": "^1.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-render-html": "^0.6.0",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.23",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-script": "^2.0.5",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-search-autocomplete": "^5.4.4",
    "react-select": "^4.3.1",
    "react-select-search": "^3.0.9",
    "react-share": "^4.4.1",
    "react-sparklines": "^1.7.0",
    "react-star-ratings": "^2.3.0",
    "react-switch": "^6.0.0",
    "react-timer-hook": "^3.0.5",
    "react-to-print": "^2.14.4",
    "react-toastr": "^3.0.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.9.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "rsuite": "^5.24.1",
    "simplebar-react": "^2.3.3",
    "socket.io": "^4.4.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.4.1",
    "source-map-explorer": "^2.5.2",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "url-exist": "^3.0.0",
    "url-exists": "^1.0.3",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "validator": "^13.7.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.18.0",
    "npm": "8.3.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "moment": "2.24.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^8.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.1.3",
    "dotenv": "^8.6.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.5",
    "new-url-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.27.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: How nested is your image? I have tried and it worked, so can you provide a reproducible example? You can try this loader [Resolve URL Loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-url-loader)

Comment: My image path is "src/assets/images/Rounded_Rectangle4_orders.png"

Comment: Added my folder structure above and background-image url line lies in the file _authentication.scss

Comment: I created the same structure and it still works for me, could you share a minimum reproducible example?

Comment: I'm not sure, I never tried it before, maybe you can also share, `nodejs` version, and `devDependencies` or your `package.json` if you don't have something private there

Comment: I have shared **package.json** file and nodejs version kindly check

Comment: Have you `sass-loader` installed? I can't see it on `package.json`

Comment: No, I don't have

Comment: background-image is situated in **_authentication.scss**

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Please check if the image exists and if its file ext name is correct. A working example: https://github.com/mrdulin/webpack-samples/tree/main/webpack-v5/stackoverflow/76330563